# ASP.Net, ASPX Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I am hoping someone might help me better understand or resolve a problem I am having with Firefox that I suspect may be related to a website that uses ASP.net to gather my account information and direct me to another company’s website where I am able to pay my bill online using a credit card. I am a computer user and have no programming or website development knowledge.

Each month the bill collection service provider adds a link to my profile on their secure website when they are ready for me to pay my bill which allows me to pay my bill online through a third party credit card processing company.

When I click on the link I am directed to the credit card processing company’s website where I am able to pay my bill. When I pay my bill for the current month the link disappears from my profile on the bill collection service provider’s website until the next month when they add it again when my statement closes and I owe money.
My account information is not stored on the credit card processors website it is provided each month through the redirection process using ASP.net. All the information is encrypted in the address or location field in the web browser until it is closed.

When I go through the payment process using Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8 it goes off without a hitch. If I go through the process using Firefox 3.5, 17, 18 or 19 the page is blank and stays that way. When this happened I changed Firefox’s default security certificate settings from ask for certificate information each time to acquire automatically and I changed Firefox’s settings to open new links in a new browser window instead of a new tab so I would have 2 separate browser processes with their own address fields like Internet Explorer behaves by default out of the box but that did not resolve the problem. If I click on the security certificate information in the address bar I can see the information related to the bill collection service provider but not the information for the credit card processors website related to the blank page that opened.

Your assistance would be appreciated

Sincerely,
Mark